# How to make a faster algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

Let  = (, ) be a directed graph with edge weights and let  be a vertex of . All of the edge weights are integers between 1 and 20. Design an algorithm for finding the shortest paths from . The running time of your algorithm should be asymptotically faster than Dijkstra’s running time.

I know that Dijkstra’s running time is O( e + v log v), and try to find a faster algorithm.

If all weights are 1 or only include 0 and 1, I can use BFS O(e+v) in a directed graph, but how to make a faster algorithm for edge weights are integers between 1 and 20.

Comment: Any other constraints? like |V| or |E|?

Comment: sorry, running time just need faster than  O( |E| + |V| log V)

Comment: Hmm, the edited question now looks quite blur, any reason why you stripped out the details? Otherwise, I will need to revert it.

Comment: I put back the original description, as the edited one is ambiguous for others, which is not aligned with this community's benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Well let`s say you have an edge that goes from u to v with weight
   w
2. We can insert w-1 extra nodes between nodes u and v
3. So after
   modifying each edge (which takes O(20*E)) we have a graph where
   every edge is 1
4. And on such graph we can use regular BFS, we will have atmost 20*N
   new nodes, and 20*E new edges so complexity is still O(V+E)

i.e.

[image]

This gets transformed to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  I understand this step, and I'm sure it works if this is an undirected graph, but is this works in a directed graph?  because All of the edge weights are integers between 1 and 20.

Comment: @Talor Yes it works for both directed & unidrected graphs, updated answer to include a visual example.